# How to import form Json file to MongoDb

Tags: json, windows, mongodb, import, database

How to import a json file to mongodb? 
I tried:

```
mongoimport --db test --collection restaurants --drop --file primer-dataset.json
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mongoimport is a stand-alone application that needs to be executed from the shell, (Window Command Prompt, Bash, etc). It seems you are currently executing the code inside the Mongo shell itself.

Answer (score 1):

The [docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/) read:

> The mongoimport tool imports content from an Extended JSON, CSV, or TSV export **created by mongoexport**, or **potentially**, another third-party export tool.

The word "potentially" means it should be a **valid** json with expected structure. Not an arbitrary json.